# How to indent existing OCaml code

Tags: ocaml, indentation

I have ~30.000 lines of badly indented OCaml code (including mly and mll files) and would like to indent them. I tried googling for variations of 'ocaml indent' the closest I can get is to use Omlet.vim and indent the code one line at a time (via C-f in insert mode). Is there a way to do the indentation for all the 30000 lines?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use Emacs as my editor with this package installed:

http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/u3-ocaml/emacs/index.html

To indent existing code you need to highlight it and then use the key combination `C-M-\`

You can script this per file pretty easily and I find the indentation to be pretty good.

Comment: You can do the same thing in tuareg-mode with `M-q`. Don't know how it scales to thousands of lines though.

Comment: @Chris, you're correct.  I did use tuareg when I started learning OCaml and I do think it's more popular than the package hosted on the inria site.  I just happen to prefer the package I posted.  But take that with a grain of salt as I'm not the most polished OCaml programmer around;)

Answer (score 3):

When I want to re-indent a whole file in vim, I use the following key sequence:

<kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd>

Breaking this down for you, <kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>g</kbd> moves the cursor to the beginning of the file.  <kbd>V</kbd> enters visual mode.  <kbd>G</kbd> selects to the end of the file.  <kbd>=</kbd> indents the selected lines.

This should be much faster than your method of applying indentation line by line, but yet will use the same rules (warning: using Omlet, indenting a whole file may take a while).

Answer (score 3):

Now, one can use ocp-indent (opam install ocp-indent) and invoke it like this :

```
ocp-indent bad-indented-ocaml.ml > well-indented-file.ml
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ocp-indent` tool for this. Here is an example `Makefile` rule, that will automatically indent you `ml` files.

```
.PHONY: auto-ocp-indent
auto-ocp-indent: *.ml
    for mlfile in $^; do ocp-indent -i $$mlfile; done
```